# Use the word "Works" to mean "Projects"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, grammatical-number

Suppose I have done some computer projects (i.e. built some programs). Now instead of the word "**projects**" I want to use "**work**". How can I use it to mean projects?

> **Work** or **Works**?

Do they convey the same meaning? If so, which one (project or work) do you think is better to use in this case?

Comment: This is highly dependent on context.  You need to give us the specific scenarios you're considering.

Comment: What variety of English are you asking about? In the country I'm visiting just now they seem to say "a works" when I would say "a construction project".

Comment: Your question might be better-received if you could indicate *why* you want to use the word *work* — *projects* is well-understood and conventional. Referring to software projects as your *works* in American English sounds incredibly pretentious and egocentric.

Comment: @ThePhoton in the UK and, I think the US as well, "a works" or "the works" would be a large industrial site such as a steelworks, a chemical plant or an oil refinery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *computer projects* is the more typical and understood choice.
The noun *work* could refer to a singular piece, as in *a work of art*. Similarly *works* could refer to multiple such pieces, *The Great Works of Western Literature*. Unfortunately *a program work* or *computer works* isn't clearly understandable compared to classical art.

However, *work* is also a verb, as in *I work on computer programs*, as well as a mass noun as in *I do a lot of programming work*. Not to mention the present tense *He works on computers*. It also means *to function* as in *That broken computer doesn't work very well*.

Better to use *project* and avoid all that.